# Data Reader Returning null although it says it has an item there

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello I am using a reader to get a XML from a stored procedure.. now the stored procedure returns null if it does not find anything .. in the case I am testing.. it should not return anything but my code is failing.. it says there is a row.. but then when it gets to the reader.GetString(0); it says `Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.`

How can I check for null int hat line XML = XML + reader.GetString(0);? it is passing the while(reader.Read() && reader.HasRows) check.. when I debug it says there is an item but then when it gets to the line mentioned above it throws the Data is null error. How can I fix this?

Here is my code

```
   SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        string XML = "";

        while (reader.Read() && reader.HasRows)
        {
               XML = XML + reader.GetString(0); 
        }

        XML = "<ProductList>" + XML + "</ProductList>";

        reader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();

        return XML;
```

Comment: not related to the answer, but what is "xmlOut"

Comment: ahh its a mistake..  changing now

Comment: So the question is how can I check for that null?, so that it does not cause an error

Comment: The thing is that it passes the while() check... and throws the error here XML = XML + reader.GetString(0);

Comment: Fyi, I think reader.Read() && reader.HasRows is redundant, all you really need is while(reader.Read()), if you want it cleaner you should do:  if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               // stuff
            }
        }

Comment: @user710502 - you can check for nulls with IsDBNull(index).  See my answer for a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.isdbnull.aspx) first:

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
{
    XML = XML + reader.GetString(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsDBNull method to check for null:

```
while (reader.Read())         
{
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
    {        
        XML = XML + reader.GetString(0)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** Removed the reader.HasRows call as it's redundant (as pointed out by someone else).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct, the while (reader.Read() will make it go through the loop once even if there isn't data.  Could be mistaken on that though.   Couple things you can try are changing it to have a nested if like

```
while(reader.read())
{
     if(reader.HasRows)
     {
      XML = XML + reader.GetString(0);
     }
}
```

I would change the GetString(0) to GetValue(0).ToString();    May not make a difference but GetString and GetValue behave differently when nulls are involved.

Comment: No that would be the do{ }while()